# MenuStrip: can't disable item

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to disable some of objects in menuToolStrip. But it can't find the objects:

```
public void ModeForStudent()
        {
            this.menuStrip1.questionToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            this.menuStrip1.accessToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: Does that code even compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try referencing them directly:

```
this.questionToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
this.accessToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
```